# fastest way search ip in large ip/subnet list on golang?

Tags: go

please help me solve next task in fastest possible way

i have a large list of ip/subnets like ...

```
35.132.199.128/27
8.44.144.248/32
87.117.185.193
45.23.45.45
```

etc
and i'll need to find some ip in that list fastes as possible in go.

when i try use slice of strings and range, it was very slow on large list.

may i use map, like map[string]string, and its look usable but only for ip checking, not for subnet checking.

anyone can help me with solving this task? thanks.

my code

```
func (app *application) validateIP(ip string) bool {

for _, item := range app.IPList {

    itemIsIP := net.ParseIP(item)

    if itemIsIP != nil {
        if ip == itemIsIP.String() {
            return true
        }
        continue
    }

    _, itemNet, err := net.ParseCIDR(item)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("[ERROR] %+v", err)
    }

    checkedIP := net.ParseIP(ip)

    if itemNet.Contains(checkedIP) {
        return true
    }
}
return false
```

}

Comment: convert the ip + CIDR mask to 5 bytes and store them in a uint, then use the resultant number as a map key.   If you want to find which range a particular ip falls in then that would be slightly more complicated

Comment: What is a "very large list"? Are you using a binary search? Are you certain the code is slow because of iterating over the list, or because you're converting every string to an ip&mask for every comparison?

Comment: at this moment in list 200k records, updated first post with code

Comment: You're parsing every string for every comparison. Wouldn't it make sense to parse those ahead of time first and see if that is performant enough? (It also might help to show where the bottleneck is from some real benchmarks)

Comment: I think a [trie](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) would be a good data structure to use here, since you're essentially doing a prefix search.  I don't have a ready-made package to recommend, although https://github.com/derekparker/trie looks decent.

Answer (score 1):

A trie is an ideal data structure for fast containment search for addresses and CIDR address blocks.
The following code shows how to use the [ipaddress-go library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/)
address trie implementation to do fast containment searches.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager of the IPAddress library.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/seancfoley/ipaddress-go/ipaddr"
)

func main() {
    addrStrs := []string{
        "35.132.199.128/27", "8.44.144.248/32", "87.117.185.193", "45.23.45.45",
    }
    trie := ipaddr.AddressTrie{}
    for _, addrStr := range addrStrs {
        addr := ipaddr.NewIPAddressString(addrStr).GetAddress().ToAddressBase()
        trie.Add(addr)
    }
    fmt.Println("The trie is", trie)

    addrSearchStrs := []string{
        "35.132.199.143", "8.44.144.248", "45.23.45.45", "127.0.0.1",
    }
    for _, addrStr := range addrSearchStrs {
        addr := ipaddr.NewIPAddressString(addrStr).GetAddress().ToAddressBase()
        triePath := trie.ElementsContaining(addr)
        if triePath.Count() > 0 {
            fmt.Println("The blocks and addresses containing", addr, "are",
            triePath)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("No blocks nor addresses contain", addr)
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
The trie is 
○ 0.0.0.0/0 (4)
└─○ 0.0.0.0/1 (4)
  ├─○ 0.0.0.0/2 (3)
  │ ├─● 8.44.144.248 (1)
  │ └─○ 32.0.0.0/4 (2)
  │   ├─● 35.132.199.128/27 (1)
  │   └─● 45.23.45.45 (1)
  └─● 87.117.185.193 (1)

The blocks and addresses containing 35.132.199.143 are 
● 35.132.199.128/27 (1)

The blocks and addresses containing 8.44.144.248 are 
● 8.44.144.248 (1)

The blocks and addresses containing 45.23.45.45 are 
● 45.23.45.45 (1)

No blocks nor addresses contain 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score -1):

We solved this problem in our project:

```
isIPV4inCIDRList("35.132.199.128", []string{"35.132.199.128/27"})

func isIPV4inCIDRList(ip []byte, list []string) bool {
    for i := 0; i < 32; i++ {
        sm := strconv.Itoa(i)
        m, _ := mask(sm, 4)
        inv := andIP(ip, []byte(m))
        if len(inv) == 0 {
            continue
        }

        for _, cidr := range list {
            if cidr == inv.String() + "/" + sm {
                return true
            }
        }
    }

    return false
}

func andIP(ip, mask []byte) net.IP {
    inv := net.IP{}
    for i, v := range ip {
        inv = append(inv, mask[i]&v)
    }
    return inv
}

// Bigger than we need, not too big to worry about overflow
const big = 0xFFFFFF

// Decimal to integer.
// Returns number, characters consumed, success.
func dtoi(s string) (n int, i int, ok bool) {
    n = 0
    for i = 0; i < len(s) && '0' <= s[i] && s[i] <= '9'; i++ {
        n = n*10 + int(s[i]-'0')
        if n >= big {
            return big, i, false
        }
    }
    if i == 0 {
        return 0, 0, false
    }
    return n, i, true
}

func mask(m string, iplen int) (net.IPMask, error) {
    n, i, ok := dtoi(m)
    if !ok || i != len(m) || n < 0 || n > 8*iplen {
        return nil, &net.ParseError{Type: "CIDR address"}
    }
    return net.CIDRMask(n, 8*iplen), nil
}
```